# Change stroke of background svg on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

There is button with text and arrow image:

```css
button {
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #00aef4;
  border: 2px solid #00aef4;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 2.3;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:after {
  background: url("/svg/right-arrow.svg") no-repeat;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 8px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #00aef4;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Next</button>
```

So, I need to change stroke color of arrow on hover without javascript. How to make it possible?

**UPD** Stackoverflow doesn't allow to add content svg-file. I publush it to gist: https://gist.github.com/bibimij/a5ae9dcc309db5547a31

Comment: Create two images, one with each stroke colour you want and on hover assign the other image url to the background.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah, and then create hundreds of other images for each color you may need

Comment: @llamerr feel free to write an answer showing how you'd do it.

Comment: I ended up replacing background svg with inline svg instead with styling like this `.icon svg #icon {stroke: #aabbcc}` where svg is like `<svg ...><g id="icon"  stroke="#09194C">...<path d=...>....</svg>`. can't find in which answer I found this solution

Answer (score 1):

without seeing your svg file you could just create a new image file with the colour you need?

background: url("/svg/right-arrow-hovercolor.svg") no-repeat;

Answer (score 0):

I used svg to create an arrow try this

```css
button {
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #00aef4;
  border: 2px solid #00aef4;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 2.3;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right:30px;
}
.button svg{
  transform:scale(.5,.5);
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-45px;
  margin-left:5px;
  }
.button:hover {
  background: #00aef4;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button:hover svg path{
  fill:#00aef4;
  stroke:white;
```

```html
<button class="button">Next
<svg width="50" height="60">
     <path d=" m 0 20 30 0 0 -20 20 30 -20 30 0 -20 -30 0 "fill="white" stroke="#00aef4" stroke-width="2"/>
  </svg>
  </button>
```

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/bibimij/a5ae9dcc309db5547a31.
.button:hover svg polyline {stroke: #fff} didn't help.

Comment: @bibimij Is you svg inside the button ?

Comment: it's background of .button:after element.